# CSS: Style affects tag outside intended selector

Tags: css

Apologies if the title is a little confusing. This is what I mean:

I have the following markup:

```
<ul class="cv-section">
    <li>
        <h2>Section</h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...</p>
    </li>
    ...
```

I have the following style:

```
.cv-section h1,h2,h3,h4,h5 {
    text-align: left;
    color: red; /*for debugging*/
}
```

However, the style is taking effect on the following h2 tag:

```
<div class="content-wrapper">
    <article>
        <h1>About Title</h1>
        <p class="lede">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
        <h2>About Title h2</h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
    </article>
</div>
```

The CSS selector specifies that the headers be descendants of .cv-section but the h2 tag within article is red and aligns to the left despite there not be a single occurrence of .cv-section on the page.

What am I doing wrong?

(Tested in Chrome and Firefox.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be like this. .cv-section h1 will affect all h1 inside the div cv-section but when you separate it with comma you are defining a new rule.

```
.cv-section h1,
.cv-section h2,
.cv-section h3,
.cv-section h4,
.cv-section h5 {
    text-align: left;
    color: red; 
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to repeat the `.cv-section` in your rule for each element:

```
.cv-section h1, .cv-section h2, .cv-section h3, .cv-section h4, .cv-section h5
```

The way you have it now, only the `.cv-section h1` is being limited to existing with an element with the class of `.cv-section`